# Opening a closed application based on events from network

Tags: android, websocket, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

this is my issue:I am developing an emergency app where real time data is important, I have a backend running socket.io, and the client is an android device. Every time the backend emits a new emergency, it should be displayed for the client if the app is opened, or renders the activity (opens the application) if it's closed.
From what I read in socket.io: Socket.IO is not meant to be used as a background service for mobile applications.([source](https://socket.io/docs/v4/)).
And even if I try it, there are a lot of restriction that can make the app not work as needed (exp: time delay…)
My question, is there a way in Android to open/run the application based on events coming from network?
cordially,

Comment: Post specific event from server and have a broadcast actively listening and open ups app on specified event? Does this approach solve the problem? Doing so you don't have your app running in background 24/7

Comment: There's FCM (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) should be able to do what you want

Comment: @DanBaruch  FCM will not render the activity, it shows a notification that can pass unnoticed if the phone is on silent

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah can you explain more please?

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that you can use FCM to pop up your activity to the front, I might have misread then